# Why does apache block viewvc (error 403) with error "client denied by server configuration"?

Tags: 16.04, apache2, svn

I can't get viewvc working in Ubuntu 16.04. (The same setup worked in Ubuntu 15.10.) The error message in /var/log/apache2/error.log is:

```
[authz_core:error] [pid 24296]
 [client 192.168.1.34:37586] AH01630: client denied by server configuration:
 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi
```

Here's what I did. I installed the package:

```
sudo apt install viewvc
```

configured `/etc/viewvc/viewvc.conf`:

```
[general]
root_parents = /data/svnrepo : svn

[options]
root_as_url_component = 1
allowed_views = annotate, diff, markup, roots, co
template_dir = /etc/viewvc/templates
```

set up an Apache virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin smith@localhost
    ServerName svn.example.com
    Alias /docroot /usr/share/viewvc/docroot
    ScriptAlias / /usr/lib/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/>
     Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/share/viewvc/docroot>
     Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

enabled it and restarted apache (with no errors):

```
sudo a2ensite svn.example.com.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

but whenever I hit svn.example.com, I get this error:

```
Sun Sep 25 14:25:24.430254 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 24296]
 [client 192.168.1.34:37586] AH01630: client denied by server configuration:
 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi, referer: http://svn.example.com/
```

I have already tried (without solving the problem):

- Installing libapache2-svn
- Deleting all the `AllowOverride` and `Require` directives from `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
- Using Apache 2.2 syntax (`Order allow, deny`, `Allow from all`)
- Adding `Options FollowSymLinks` and `ExecCGI`
- `AddHandler cgi-script cgi`
- `iptables -F`
- The advice on [this page](https://serverfault.com/questions/418101/apache-client-denied-by-server-configuration-despite-allowing-access-to-direc)

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that [the CGI module is not enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403067/cgi-bin-not-working), so the `ScriptAlias` command wasn't working. The solution was:

```
$ sudo a2enmod cgi
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

and refresh the browser.

I was also able to simplify the Apache config by removing the `<Directory>` parts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin smith@localhost
    ServerName svn.example.com
    Alias /docroot /usr/share/viewvc/docroot
    ScriptAlias / /usr/lib/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks to [C. Michael Pilato](https://github.com/cmpilato) for helping to point me in the right direction.